# Is it possible to apply metadata to file where user has Write Only access?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, spfx, file-upload, metadata

This issue stems from a custom interface I'm creating for uploading files. In my situation, the uploading user is required to have write-only access to the destination library. So they can upload files, but after that they cannot modify or delete them. This is all possible with SharePoint permissions. However, I also need to tag the document with metadata as part of the upload process. The code I'm using to upload the files is a 2-step process - upload the file, then get the file (and the underlying SharePoint "item") and then apply the metadata to the item. Unfortunately, this won't work because that 2nd step is a modification, and the user doesn't have the permissions to do that.

I don't think this issue is limited to custom code, as I get the same problem using the standard document library interface. I upload a file, but I then can't set metadata, even if it's a required field.

I guess I'm just looking for options here. Is it possible to upload a file in code, and apply metadata, all in one step? The code I'm using at the moment is along the following lines:

```
  sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('**PATH**')  
      .files.addChunked(myfile.name, myfile)
      .then(({ file }) => file.getItem()).then((item:any) => {  
        console.log("File Uploaded");  
        this.setState({});
        return item.update({  
            /* Set Metadata here */
            Title: 'Metadata Updated'  
        }).then();  
      })
```

Cheers all.

Comment: Not possible using PnPJS at least. :(

Comment: Possible any other way, in a web part?